# Facebook Asp.net sdk switch api version

Tags: facebook, api, sdk, facebook-fql, version

I'm using facebook sdk v6.4.2.
but api version 2.1, I get the error when i use fql :/
Error : fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher

I want to use the low version : 2.0

Thanks

Comment: There is no official .NET SDK, so what are you using?

Comment: Facebook sdk : https://www.nuget.org/packages/facebook

Answer (score 1):

There's aguide for using versionned Graph API calls at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/quickstart/v2.1#versions

If you're even able to execute calls to older versions of the Graph API is determined by the creation date of the app you're using. Have a look at my answer here:

[Query Facebook for what version of the Graph API is being used / can be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256428/query-facebook-for-what-version-of-the-graph-api-is-being-used-can-be-used/25258886#25258886)

Comment: but i cant use it :/
My Project asp.net and my code :
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.q = name;
        parameters.type = "user";
        dynamic me = client.Get("fql", new { q = "SELECT uid,first_name,last_name,name,pic,profile_update_time,is_app_user,online_presence,profile_url FROM user WHERE contains('" + name + "')" });
        dynamic result = client.Get("search", parameters);

Comment: Is your app pre-v2.1? If yes, try `dynamic me = client.Get("/v2.0/fql", new { q = "SELECT uid,first_name,last_name,name,pic,profile_update_time,is_app_user,online_presenc‌​e,profile_url FROM user WHERE contains('" + name + "')" });`

Comment: My problem, using fql query in asp.net project.
but I get an error : fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher

Comment: Please answer my question: Is your app pre-v2.1, meaning created before Augist 7th 2014?

Comment: Then you can't use v2.0 and FQL then. As written in the docs and the answer I linked.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Class definition for FacebookClient you can find Version property. So, create new FacebookClient and set Version:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
client.Version = "2.1";
```